# Executing radio button click upon clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html, radio-group

I have a group of radio buttons and upon clicking a link I want to execute one of the radio buttons in the group...in this case the one with an Id="IndividualPD".

This is the html for the radio buttons

```
<div class="btn-group" id="performanceRadioBtns" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-     top: 20px; float: right">
   <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="PDStatus">
        PD Status
   </label>

   <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="PDRating">
        PD Rating
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-primary">
     <input type="radio" name="options" id="IndividualPD">
     Individual PD
   </label>
</div>
```

This is the jquery for what I have tried.

```
$("#performanceRadioBtns").find("#IndividualPD").find("input[name='options']").trigger("change");
```

but doesnt activate the button.

Help perhaps on how to 'trigger' this button upon clicking a link

Comment: If your IDs are unique as they should be, you'll only just `$('#IndividualPD')` to get to the radio button.

Comment: What does it mean when you say "execute" one of the radiobuttons? The change-event will be triggered on clicking the radiobutton even without the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the radio button, you need to use `prop("checked", true)`

As well as changing your selector to:

```
$("#performanceRadioBtns").find("#IndividualPD").prop("checked", true);
```

since `#IndividualPD` is already the `input` element